# Spring Boot Security - redirect from http 8080 to https 433 don't work that I expected

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, redirect, spring-security

I need help. I created simple project with spring security. But redirect from 8080 to 433 don't work that I expected.

```
    @Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    // Enable SSL Traffic
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
    };

    // Add HTTP to HTTPS redirect
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(httpToHttpsRedirectConnector());

    return tomcat;
}

private Connector httpToHttpsRedirectConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setPort(8080);
    connector.setSecure(false);
    connector.setRedirectPort(443);
    return connector;
}
```

After auto-redirect from localhoste:8080/ the url looks like this: 
https://localhost

Server is not response. I have to add port number manually to url like that:
https://localhost:443/

my application.properties:

```
server.port=433
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/ssl_security.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=secret
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias=ssl_security
```

I did something wrong? Or maybe this some my web browser configuration?

Below link to github:

https://github.com/scina/SpringBootSecurity

Comment: There are standard ports. For `HTTPS` Port `443` and for `HTTP` it is port `80`. Since you are redirecting to standard port browser tries to remove the clutter on the domain name. I think it is implicit that `https://localhost` is sending communicating at port `443`

Comment: I found my mistake. Ports ssl isn't equals (433 and 443). When I fixed this, app works that I am expecting. Sorry for my stupid question. How to close this subject?